# pyzmq proxy in a strange state after subscribing multiple processes

Tags: python, proxy, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm having a weird issue with the proxy in pyzmq. Here's the code of that proxy:

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context.instance()

frontend_socket = context.socket(zmq.XSUB)
frontend_socket.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:%s" % sub_port)

backend_socket = context.socket(zmq.XPUB)
backend_socket.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:%s" % pub_port)

zmq.proxy(frontend_socket, backend_socket)
```

I'm using that proxy to send messages between ~50 processes that run on 6 different machines. The total amount of topics is around 1,000, but since multiple processes can listen on the same topics, the total amount of subscriptions is around 10,000.

In normal times this works very well, messages go through the proxy correctly as long as a process publishes it and at least one other processes is subscribed to the topic. It works whether the publisher or subscriber was started first.

But at some point in time, when we start a new process (let's call it X), it starts behaving strangely. Everything that was already connected keeps working, but the new processes that we connect can only get messages to go through if the publisher is connected before the subscriber. X can be any one of the processes that normally work, and it can be from any machine, and the result is the same. When we get in this state, killing X makes everything work again, and starting it again makes it fail. If we stop other processes and then start X, it works well (so it's not related with X's code in particular).

I'm not sure if we could be reaching some limit of ZMQ? I've read examples of people that seem to have way more processes, subscriptions, etc. than us. It could be some option that we should set on the proxy, so far here are the ones we've tried without success:

- Changing RCVHWM on frontend_socket
- Changing SNDHWM on backend_socket
- Setting XPUB_VERBOSE on backend_socket
- Setting XPUB_VERBOSER on backend_socket

Here is sample code of how we publish messages to the proxy:

```
topic = "test"
message = {"test": "test"}

context = zmq.Context.instance()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.connect("tcp://1.2.3.4:1234")
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    socket.send_multipart([topic.encode(), json.dumps(message).encode()])
```

Here is sample code of how we subscribe to messages from the proxy:

```
topic = "test"
context = zmq.Context.instance()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://1.2.3.4:5678")
socket.subscribe(topic)

while True:
    multi_part = socket.recv_multipart()
    [topic, message] = multi_part
    print(topic.decode(), message.decode())
```

Has anyone ever seen a similar issue? Is there something we can do to avoid the proxy getting in this state?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all the publishers (proxy and publish process) XPUB ( + sockopt verbose/verboser) then read from the publisher sockets on a poll loop. The first byte of the subscription message will tell you if the message is sub/unsub followed by the subject/topic. If you log all of the this information with timestamps it should tell you which component is at fault (it could be any of the three) and help with a fix.

The format of the subscription messages that arrive on the publisher (XPUB) will be

- Subscription `[0x01][topic]`
- Unsubscription `[0x00][topic]`

### Code needed

I usually work on C++ but this is the general idea in python

#### proxy

You need to create a capture socket (this acts like a network tap). You connect a ZMQ_PAIR socket to the proxy (capture) over inproc and then read the contents at the other end of the socket. As you are using XPUB/XSUB you will see the subscription messages.

`zmq.proxy(frontend, backend, capture)`

read the docs/examples for the python proxy.

#### publisher

In this case you need to read from the publishing socket in the same thread as you are sending on it. That's the reason I said a poll loop might be best.

This code is not tested at all.

```
topic = "test"
message = {"test": "test"}

context = zmq.Context.instance()
socket = context.socket(zmq.XPUB)
socket.connect("tcp://1.2.3.4:1234")

poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
timeout = 1000  #ms

while True:
  socks = dict(poller.poll(timeout))
  if not socks : # 1
    socket.send_multipart([topic.encode(), json.dumps(message).encode()])
  if socket in socks:
    sub_msg = socket.recv()  
    # print out the message here.
```

Comment: Hi James, when you say "read from the publisher sockets on a poll loop" I'm not quite sure how to do that. If I simply connect another subscriber to it (and subscribe to everything), will I receive all the sub/unsub from all the other processes? Or is there another way to read what's happening in the XPUB socket? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Carl, I updated the answer with more details as they wouldnt fit in here. Keep in mind my python skills are poor so you will need to check out the exact zmq python commands yourself

Comment: Sorry for the delay on that, it was a bit hard to test since it doesn't happen often. But this morning it happened and I was able to play with the code you provided. I notice that when I start a new publisher, it receives a list of exactly 1,000 subscribed topics (which really looks like some kind of limit number). Then, if new subscribers are created afterwards, it receives the new topics. So when the subscriber is created first and its topic is not in the list of 1,000 topics, we get an issue because the publisher never knows about it. I'll see if this 1,000 limit can be changed.

Comment: I just fixed the issue using this information, we had to set SNDHWM on frontend_socket, because that's actually the one that sends the existing subscriptions to the new publishers. Note that I also set RCVHWM on backend_socket but I'm not sure it's relevant.

Comment: perfect, I am glad the code to debug subscriptions flagged up the issue. I have had that exact same issue in the past where a proxy got overloaded with subscription messages when processes where coming up/down